# How do I spell out an integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module, integer

Does anyone know of a Ruby module that will take an integer and spell it out ( 1 => "one", 2 => "two", etc..)?

Comment: Another gem - https://github.com/markburns/numbers_in_words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

http://mike-burns.com/project/integer_to_word/